# Regex - don't understand why there's no match

Tags: regex, syntax, pattern-matching, syntax-highlighting

I'm currently trying to write a small syntax highlighting script where I have the following regex:

```
[^\w](int|for)[^\w]|^(int|for)[^\w]|(int|for)$
```

Now when I type

```
for int
```

With a space after the last int, the for gets highlighted but the int doesn't and I don't understand why. I was thinking that " int " is matching the regex.

When I try to type

```
bla bla for bla bla
```

The for gets highlighted. Could anyone explain me why " int " is not matching with the above regex?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to do with your `$` (assert position at end of line) - try and remove it and it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah it's working now :) but could you please explain a little more why this happened?

Comment: @Devos50 He already stated that `$` will only match if it's the end of a line.

Comment: I have abandoned my edit as Rohit has been far more eloquent with his explanation.